# Copying final list to another list?

Tags: java, list

If the list is final can it be copied to another list so if we make changes in new list the original one doesn't get affected ?

```
public class Solution {
// DO NOT MODIFY THE LIST
public int maximumGap(final List<Integer> a) {
    if(a.size()<2)return 0;
    List<Integer> c=new List<Integer>(a);
    Collections.sort(c);
    return c.get(c.size()-1)-c.get(c.size()-2);
}
```

}

Comment: and ... why not ?

Comment: If it is copy so you are changing a copy not the previous instance.

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: can you tell me the code to achieve the stated?

Comment: final list can be copied... where is the code with your try??

Comment: public class Solution {
 // DO NOT MODIFY THE LIST
 public int maximumGap(final List<Integer> a) {
     if(a.size()<2)return 0;
     List<Integer> c=new List<Integer>(a);
     Collections.sort(c);
     return c.get(c.size()-1)-c.get(c.size()-2);
 }
}

Comment: You can even manipulate the incoming list, it doesn't matter if it is final or not. When you don't want that someone can modify your list, then expect a immutable list, like Guavas ImmutableList type.

Comment: @Tom or the result from `Collections.unmodifiableList()` from standard Java

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I prefer ImmutableList, because no one can modify your underlying data structure. `Collections.unmodifiableList()` just returns an immutable _view_ and you can still modify the original list. Might be alright for this case here, but I would still generally recommend Guava :D.

Comment: @Tom I prefer not using any external library, if possible... but this does not matter for this question anyways [:-)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler must be stating

> Cannot instantiate the type List

since `List` is an interface and not an class.

A class must be given like in

```
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you copy a list into another one, then they are independent regardless of the **final** keyword.

Comment: please improve this comment so it looks more like an answer